# How to change action button color in ppt with VB

Tags: vba, powerpoint

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EEZsT.png)I am creating a simple MCQ quiz in PPT with VB script. Would like to change the color of the Action Button(not the msgbox) containing the answers for right/wrong attempt.
This is what I have coded so far and it is working fine.

```
Dim numberCorrect As Integer
Dim numberWrong As Integer
Dim Shape As Shape

Sub Correct()
    MsgBox "Well Done! Correct Answer.", vbApplicationModal, " e-Aarohan Quiz "
    numberCorrect = numberCorrect + 1
End Sub

Sub Wrong()
    MsgBox "Sorry! Wrong Answer.", vbApplicationModal, " e-Aarohan Quiz "
    numberWrong = numberWrong + 1
End Sub
```

Comment: Please include some references like screenshots, code samples, etc. so the user has better clarity. Please See [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: What is this Action button?

Comment: If you're asking how o change the color of a button on a MsgBox, the answer is =, you can't.  You can, however, create your own message dialog and format it how you like.

Comment: I am not trying to change the color of MsgBox.

Comment: I am not trying to change the color of MsgBox. Every question has 4 options for answer. When one clicks on the right or wrong option, the relevant Pop-up(MsgBox) is displayed. I have coded this part. What I want to do is - based on the right or wrong option the color of the textbox(action button) containing the answer will also change. It will turn Green for correct answer and Red for wrong answer. Hope I was able to explain my requirement. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Add this macro to your project and assign the action button's Action Setting to Run Macro: ActionButton

```
Sub ActionButton(oSh As Shape)
' This will hand you a reference to the clicked
' action button in oSh
' Use that to determine what to do next

' But to change the foreground color, e.g. to blue
With oSh
    .Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(0, 0, 255)
End With

End Sub
```